# Is label encoding needed when using TfidfVectorizer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-classification

Probably a very newbie question:

I'm working on a multi-class text classification project where all my features and labels are text based.

It has just came to my understanding that I'm not encoding the features and labels since I was relaying on the below:

```
def _create_transformer_from_feature_columns(columns):
    tuples = []
    for col in list(columns):
        tfidf_kwargs = {'ngram_range': (1, 2), 'sublinear_tf': True}
        if col not in NON_LEMMATIZED_COLUMN_NAMES:
            tfidf_kwargs.update({'tokenizer': Tokenizer()})
        tuples.append((f'vec_{col}', TfidfVectorizer(**tfidf_kwargs), col))

    return ColumnTransformer(tuples, remainder='passthrough')

df_list = []
for bug in useful_bugs_dict.values():
    # convert bug data into feature metric
    bug_data = bug.get_data_as_df()
    group_name = bug_data['group_name'][0]
    if group_name not in group_owners_dict:
        owner_id = len(group_owners_dict)
        group_owners_dict[group_name] = owner_id
        group_owner_id_dict[owner_id] = group_name

    df_list.append(bug_data)

training_data = pd.concat(df_list)
training_data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

columns = training_data.drop('group_name', axis='columns').columns
transformer = _create_transformer_from_feature_columns(columns)



labels = training_data['group_name']
features = training_data.drop('group_name', axis='columns')

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, labels, test_size=0.2)
```

Also I'm using XGBClassifier and I'm getting this warning:

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py:1146: 
UserWarning: The use of label encoder in XGBClassifier is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. 
To remove this warning, do the following: 
1) Pass option use_label_encoder=False when constructing XGBClassifier object; 
and 2) Encode your labels (y) as integers starting with 0, i.e. 0, 1, 2, ..., [num_class - 1].
  warnings.warn(label_encoder_deprecation_msg, UserWarning)
```

I was under the impression will do it for me.

Was I wrong?

Comment: this is only warning that they may change it in the future - and it even shows you how to fix it. Did you try it?

Comment: @furas my question was not regarding (only) the warning.
Anyway - it has already been answered.

Comment: @furas well... I guess it's just you since I've already been answered by someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning is unrelated to `TfidfVectorizer`. Its `fit` and `fit_transform` methods only rely on `X` to compute the tf-idf-weighted document-term matrix. `y` is ignored in both cases and its encoding is irrelevant.

For the `scikit-learn` classifiers, encoding `y` is also not mandatory. Passing string value objects in classification problems is usually not a problem. Note that the following code for a multiclass problem will execute without any issues:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier


X = ['doc one', 'doc two', 'number three']
y = [['yes', 'ok'], ['yes', 'not okay'], ['no', 'not okay']]

vec = TfidfVectorizer()
Xt = vec.fit_transform(X, y)

clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf.fit(Xt, y)
```

The warning however is from the `XGBClassifier`  which is not from `scikit-learn`. And apparently, the internal encoding of `y` *is deprecated and will be removed in a future release*. So in this particular case, you will have to do it explicitly yourself *in the future*, e.g when you use the next version(s).